# Possible to Use "document.referrer" in iFrame URL?

Tags: javascript, iframe

We have embedded tutorial youtube videos for new members of a forum, and would like to incorporate an iFrame which loads the referring forum page on our tutorial page, when they click a help video link. This would allow members to pause the video, and actually try out the instructions on the forum page they were on, without having to either tab back and forth, or having two browser windows open. We tried using popup videos, but didn't work well for our purposes.

Is there a way to load a referring page in an iFrame such as:

```
<iframe src="document.referrer" style="width: 640px; height: 480px" name="forumvids"></iframe>
```

Nothing has worked so far. We end up just getting a blank iFrame window.  Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: src expects a URL, not javascript. you need something like $(document).ready(function(){ $('iframe').attr('src',document.referrer)}); didn't post as an answer as it's not tested and probably won't work, but this is the starting point

Answer (score 2):

`src="document.referrer"` is a string there, it has no idea you are talking about JavaScript. Set it with JavaScript such as:

```
<iframe id="iframeId"></iframe>
<script>
    var ifr = document.getElementById("iframeId");
    ifr.src = document.referrer;
</script>
```

Just a warning, document.referrer does not always have a value.

Answer (score 1):

Converting my comment to an answer (after testing it, and removing JQuery dependency)

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    if(document.referrer!=null){
        //alert(document.referrer); comment in for testing 
        document.getElementById("frame").src = document.referrer;
    }

}
</script>

<iframe id="frame" />
```

Answer (score 1):

**I would use :**

```
<script>
document.write(parent.document.referrer);
</script>
```

Beny

Comment: Please provide more details. This isn't very helpful in this form.

Comment: Why downvote ? This line will write the referrer URL, over an iFrame.